# cancel button php form jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

These are the buttons on my form:

```
<input type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn" name="save" value="verzenden" />
<input type="submit" name="cancel" class="btn" value="annuleren" />
```

I catch the cancel click with php like this:

```
if($_POST['cancel'])
{
    Helper::redirect('page.php');
}
```

But before I submit my form, I use some jQuery to validate the form, now I can't click cancel because it will validate first.

This is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#cancel').delegate('','click change',function(){
            console.log('test');
        });

        $('form').submit(function(){
            var proceed = true;

            $('.required').each(function(){
                if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == '0') {
                    $(this).css('border-color', '#F00');
                    proceed = false;
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css('border-color', '#999');
                }
            });


            return proceed;
        });

        // Check on typing if a required field is empty
        $('.required').keyup(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == '0' ) 
                $(this).css('border-color', '#F00');
            else 
                $(this).css('border-color', '#999');
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

How can I ignore the jQuery and redirect to page.php when I hit cancel?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use JavaScript to redirect to the page when clicking the cancel button? Submitting a form just to discard it and redirect is kind of a waste of bandwidth and time.

Comment: Remember that client-side validation is in no way secure.

Comment: thanks I'll try the javascript redirect, and I also have php validation

Comment: this works, but I still see the validation (red borders) for a second, before it redirects, how can use something like php exit() in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got now:
Thanks ThiefMaster

//javascript

```
$('#cancel').delegate('','click change',function(){
    window.location = "testimonials.php";
    return false;
});
```

//php

```
if($_POST['cancel'])
{
    Helper::redirect('testimonials.php');
}
```

//html

```
<input name="cancel" type="submit" id="cancel" class="btn" value="annuleren" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#cancel').delegate('','click change',function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

This will not work, while you don't have any element in your form with id cancel

Change that button

```
<input type="submit" name="cancel" class="btn" value="annuleren" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" id="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn" value="annuleren" />
```

Comment: Sorry but I mispelled the html :$